# How to create a Python script to automate software installation?

Tags: python, automation, installation

I want to automate the software installation process. The scenario is as follows:

> Run the installation file. On first screen it has two buttons next, cancel. On click of next it goes to next screen having two buttons, next, cancel and some input data is required. After details are provided, it will show finish or cancel button.

I want to write a Python script that would automate this activity. It should identify the button and click it. It should enter the data wherever required and finish the installation. To achieve this functionality:

1. Python API is required, if any?
2. Some code samples or link of the tutorials to use the same.

Sample image for reference:

[image: Sample image for reference]

Comment: Do you want python to navigate through a graphical installer, or do you want to _make_ a graphical installer with python?

Comment: Hey Rawing, The first option, python to navigate GUI installer.

Comment: I've never used it myself, but you can take a look at [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.googlecode.com/hg/pywinauto/docs/index.html).

Comment: id like a linux solution too, that does wget extraction etc

Answer (score 16):

As Rawing mentioned, pywinauto is good choice for Windows installer. Here is nice sample video: http://pywinauto.github.io/


For waiting next page use something like that: `app.WizardPageTitle.wait('ready')`
When installer finished: `app.FinishPage.wait_not('visible')`
For edit box input: `app.WizardPage.Edit.type_keys('some input path', with_spaces=True)`
For button clicks I'd recommend `click_input()` as more reliable method.

If you want to install the app on many machines automatically, you can create Remote Desktop or VNC session and run local copy of the Python script inside that session. Just do not minimize RDP or VNC window to prevent GUI context loss. Losing focus is safe and you can continue your work on master machine in another window without affecting remote installation.


Example of easy install script for FastStone Image Viewer 4.6:

```
import os
from pywinauto.application import Application

fsv = Application(backend="win32").start("FSViewerSetup46.exe")

fsv.InstallDialog.NextButton.wait('ready', timeout=30).click_input()
fsv.InstallDialog.IAgreeRadioButton.wait('ready', timeout=30).click_input()
fsv.InstallDialog.Edit.Wait('ready', timeout=30).type_keys(os.getcwd() + "\FastStone Image Viewer", with_spaces=True)
fsv.InstallDialog.InstallButton.wait('ready', timeout=30).click_input()
fsv.InstallDialog.FinishButton.wait('ready', timeout=30).click_input()
```

Comment: Thank you Vasily! Really a great help. This solves the purpose for Windows environment. It would be great if you could tell me the similar library for Linux environment.

Comment: Look at `pyatspi` package for Linux. It uses AT SPI technology. I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Now this is Work in Progress for AT-SPI: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/pull/449 though I'm expecting it to finish in 2019.

Comment: how could you handle windows's User account control pop-up? Is there a way to waiting on it?

Comment: @AndrejovicAndrej do you mean UAC confirmation? It can’t be automated by OS design for security reasons.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov I was able to bypass it executing script as administrator

Comment: Andrejovic Andrej  how did you bypass the script as administration, i have used elevate bt it still asks for permission,

Comment: UAC must be disabled in OS settings. UAC confirmation can't be automated by design. In case of disabled UAC you can self-elevate Python process using [PyUAC](https://pypi.org/project/pyuac/).