# Software installation using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto

I am new to python.Need to install softwares (x32 bit and x64 bit) automatically using Python script..Can anyone guide me on this.Thanks in advance.

here is the code and error:

```
import os
from pywinauto.application import Application as app
inst=app.start("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\sigplus.exe")
```

> TypeError: start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cmd_line'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use python script to automate software installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901880/how-to-use-python-script-to-automate-software-installation)

Comment: yes ..tried by referring that ...but doesn't work.As a beginner Need more clear steps

Comment: try something like `from pywinauto.application import Application inst=Application().start("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\sigplus.exe")`

Comment: you should read the docs : http://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

Answer (score 2):

to install that service use:
    installutil .exe 
default path for version is:
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously wrong usage of `Application`. `start()` is not static method. You have to create `Application()` instance with round brackets and then call `.start(...)`.

```
import os
from pywinauto.application import Application as app
inst = app().start("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\sigplus.exe")
```